# Increase size of specific marker points in Anychart scatter charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, anychart, anychart-8.2

I am creating a scatter chart using [AnyChart](https://www.anychart.com/)

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    var data_1 = [["1", "82"], ["1", "90"], ["1", "78"], ["1", "86"], ["1", "86"], ["1", "88"], ["1", "86"], ["2", "87"], ["2", "90"], ["2", "87"], ["2", "90"], ["2", "67"], ["2", "90"], ["2", "77"], ["3", "82"], ["3", "96"], ["3", "82"], ["3", "80"], ["3", "93"], ["3", "67"], ["3", "87"], ["4", "66"], ["4", "91"], ["4", "71"], ["4", "77"], ["4", "77"], ["4", "80"], ["4", "83"], ["5", "76"], ["5", "82"], ["5", "62"], ["5", "78"], ["5", "84"], ["5", "78"], ["5", "76"]],
    chart = anychart.scatter();

    var series1 = chart.marker(data_1);

    series1.tooltip()
        .hAlign('start')
        .format(function () {
            return 'Value: ' + this.value;
        });

    chart.getSeriesAt(0).name("Score");

    chart.xScale().minimum(0).ticks().interval(1);
    chart.xAxis(0).drawFirstLabel(false).drawLastLabel(false);

    xLabels = chart.xAxis().labels();
    xLabels.format(function (x) {
        var xLabel;
        xLabel = x.value;
        return xLabel;
    });
    xLabels.fontSize(10);
    xLabels.width(60);
    xLabels.height(25);
    xLabels.textOverflow("...");
    xLabels.hAlign("center");

    chart.xGrid(true);
    chart.yGrid(true);
    chart.xMinorGrid(true);
    chart.yMinorGrid(true);

    chart.yScale().minimum(40);
    chart.yScale().maximum(100);
    chart.container('container');
    chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I am trying to increase the size of specific marker points on the chart.

For example: Corresponding to the x value "1" we have three "86" y values.

```
["1", "82"], ["1", "90"], ["1", "78"], ["1", "86"], ["1", "86"], ["1", "88"], ["1", "86"]
```

So I need to display that marker point with increased size. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
    var data_1 = [
          {x: "1", value: "82", size: "1"},
          {x: "1", value: "90", size: "1"},
          {x: "1", value: "78", size: "1"},
          {x: "1", value: "86", size: "3"},
          {x: "1", value: "88", size: "1"},
          {x: "2", value: "87", size: "2"},
          {x: "2", value: "90", size: "3"},
          {x: "2", value: "67", size: "1"},
          {x: "2", value: "77", size: "1"},
          {x: "3", value: "82", size: "2"},
          {x: "3", value: "96", size: "1"},
          {x: "3", value: "80", size: "1"},
          {x: "3", value: "93", size: "1"},
          {x: "3", value: "67", size: "1"},
          {x: "3", value: "87", size: "1"},
          {x: "4", value: "66", size: "1"},
          {x: "4", value: "91", size: "1"},
          {x: "4", value: "71", size: "1"},
          {x: "4", value: "77", size: "2"},
          {x: "4", value: "80", size: "1"},
          {x: "4", value: "83", size: "1"},
          {x: "5", value: "76", size: "2"},
          {x: "5", value: "82", size: "1"},
          {x: "5", value: "62", size: "1"},
          {x: "5", value: "78", size: "2"},
          {x: "5", value: "84", size: "1"},
    ];

    var chart = anychart.bubble(data_1);

    chart.tooltip()
        .hAlign('start')
        .format(function () {
            return 'Value: ' + this.value + '\n' + 'Count: ' + this.size;
        });

    chart.getSeriesAt(0).name("Score");

    chart.minBubbleSize("2%");
    chart.maxBubbleSize("4%");
    chart.xScale().minimum(0).ticks().interval(1);
    chart.xAxis(0).drawFirstLabel(false).drawLastLabel(false);

    xLabels = chart.xAxis().labels();
    xLabels.format(function (x) {
        var xLabel;
        xLabel = x.value;
        return xLabel;
    });
    xLabels.fontSize(10);
    xLabels.width(60);
    xLabels.height(25);
    xLabels.textOverflow("...");
    xLabels.hAlign("center");

    chart.xGrid(true);
    chart.yGrid(true);
    chart.xMinorGrid(true);
    chart.yMinorGrid(true);

    chart.yScale().minimum(40);
    chart.yScale().maximum(100);
    chart.container('container');
    chart.draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

do you need markers of different types sized according to the value or maybe bubble charts are what you are looking for https://playground.anychart.com/teKDUPCH ?

```
    var series1 = chart.bubble(data_1);

    chart.maxBubbleSize(20);
    chart.minBubbleSize(1);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095127/3185510 I have changed the data format and used bubble chart instead. Thanks!